# How to run xcode from terminal?

Tags: xcode, macos

My question is very simple: suppose there is an xcode project a.xcodeproj, could I open it with the command: `xcode a.xcodeproj`?

If I try this, I receive the following error message:

```
-bash: xcode: command not found
```

Comment: xcode is not a CLI application... xcodebuild is, not sure if that is what you want as you do not specify what exactly you want to acomplish.

Comment: @Brad Allred Sorry for the unclear question. I just want to open the .xodeproj project so that I can compile the codes.

Comment: I recently [released a custom script](https://github.com/jasonmccreary/oxc) I wrote to open Xcode from the command line I named `oxc`. Future readers may find it helpful.

Comment: [Nik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51297675/13082836), THANK`S. You saved my 3 hours of searching

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Xcode should be the default application for .xcodeproj files, so this should work:

```
$ open a.xcodeproj
```

If that opens a different application, you can force it to use xcode:

```
$ open -a Xcode a.xcodeproj
```

If you want the command `xcode` to work, you can just alias it:

```
$ alias xcode="open -a Xcode"
```

then you can just `xcode a.xcodeproj` (and add this to `~/.bash_profile`)

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thanx @Nirk

Comment: It is working. Now what command could be used to run an iPhone/iPad application from Xcode ?

Comment: One would need a different alias for opening xcworkspaces then, and manually tell which one to use (the xcodeproj or the xcworkspace one). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739630/3379766) can handle both with a single command.

Comment: `open` does not respect changing the toolchain with `xcode-select`, so if you use multiple versions of Xcode you can run into problems. `xed a.xcworkspace` works well.

Comment: If you make changes to your ~/.bash_profile, it's a good idea to reload your bash profile from the command line so that the changes you make actually take effect todo this :
source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 44):

You could also simply run `xed .` in the project's root directory, apparently it will try to load a project in a hierarchical manner, i.e. the first that exists:

1. the folder, if it's a Package (Xcode 11+)
2. `xcworkspace`
3. `xcodeproj`
4. `playground`

which means you don't need to verify yourself the existing file structure in order to choose the best one to open.

Comment: This should be the new top answer

Answer (score 5):

Can't remember where I came across this script, but I use this ruby script for finding either a `*.xcodeproj` or `*.xcworkspace` file in the working directory and opening that file (without Xcode opening any previous projects)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Open xcode without any previous projects being opened as well.
# We first look for a workspace, then a project in the current directory, opening the first that is found.

f = []
f.concat Dir["*.xcworkspace"]
f.concat Dir["*.xcodeproj"]

if f.length > 0
  puts "opening #{f.first}"
  `open -a /Applications/Xcode.app #{f.first} --args -ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES`
  exit 0
end

puts "No Xcode projects found"
exit 1
```

Comment: Lost this script when I upgraded my system and have been looking for it for days!! Thanks

Comment: Do you know where I could find a list of available `--args` to pass to Xcode? Like `-ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES`?

Comment: @ClayEllis especially practical from my point of view would be to have some "verbose" option, but so far I haven't found any

Comment: So basically implemented a barebones version of 'xed' (see other answers)

Comment: @emlind wow, how did I not know about this command before? Fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

open terminal, then go to the path where Xcode is installed. Then, go to its "Contents/MacOS". And when you reach this folder, then type - sudo ./Xcode

Or else follow the following code: (you can use "sudo" if the user has privilege issue)

```
cd /  
cd Applications
cd Xcode.app
cd Contents/MacOS
sudo ./Xcode
```

Answer (score 4):

Following command should do it:

```
open a.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 3):

I just type `open *xcw*`. This command looks up a workspace in the current directory and then opens is with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

incase, if you want to open a Xcode project from a workspace use the following command line.

```
user$ open -a xcode ProjectName.xcworkspace/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few functions in my `.zshrc` that accomplish what you're looking for:

```
cap () { tee /tmp/capture.out; }

ret () { cat /tmp/capture.out; }

x () {
    # Substitute .xcworkspace with .xcodeproj for your case.
    find . -type d -name "*.xcworkspace" -d 1 | cap
    xed "$(ret)"
}
```

Then, from the same directory as your `*.xcodeproj`, simply execute `x`, e.g.:

```
$ x
```