# How to open specific version of Xcode from terminal?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, terminal

How do I open a specific version of Xcode from my terminal?

I'm currently using:

```
open 'App.xcworkspace'/
```

I have multiple versions of Xcode installed from Xcode 5 to 7 Beta. I want to open the right version for the project straight from the command line without having to click on it from my Applications folder. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639914/how-to-run-xcode-from-command-line? Does this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliasing `open -a "Xcode.app" .` and `open -a "Xcode-beta.app" .` work pretty well.

Note that the `.` trick only works if there's an Xcode project or workspace file in the current directory.